# Facebook share button in my webpage is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, laravel, share

I have used facebook share script and button in my website that is hosted in Godaddy. Im also using CloudFlare for this domain.

http://adducity.gov.mv/news/21

When i try to share the news, it says unknown error occured. So than i checked it by using the facebook debugger. it shows the following error message.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "As0zRPNXMCU"
   }
}
```

This is what i have used in the body of the page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1036357999794886',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1036357999794886";

     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

For the share button this is the code

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://adducity.gov.mv/news/21" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fadducity.gov.mv%2Fnews%2F21&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: Try adding `status: true,` to the FB.init params.

Comment: @sideroxylon still the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Never tried doing what you're doing, but this is what google gave me:

> This error is caused by the URL not having the access token that the
>   API needs to process your request. Simply go to
>   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ to see the App
>   Token for your Facebook app. The App Token is a long string of numbers
>   and letters.
>
> So instead of going to
>
> connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1036357999794886
>
> Go to
>   connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1036357999794886&access_token=
>
> Now you should be able to see the results.

Anyway, the answer to your problem lies in the error message. Get the token somehow, include it in your URL's GET parameter, and it should work.

Comment: According to th FB, App token should be kept secret as they are related to the app secret. So if i include it in that line than everyone can see it.

Comment: hmm that's right, but you have to authenticate with it somehow anyway, don't you?

Comment: How to authenticate